# How do I display json data with keys inside key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I get data from an api, and this data contains one key, that last contains multiple keys, This is my example :

[image: data keys inside key]

```
{
"status": 0,
"location": "Casablanca [Doukkala-Abda;Morocco]",
  "day": {
      "1": {
      "date": "20200807",
      "name": "Friday",
      "month": "", ...
```

The parent key is the `day`

The child keys are `1`, `2`, `3` ...etc, they contains data

I tried to use `console.log(data['day']['1'])` and `console.log(data.day['1'])` but I got this error :
`Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

How do I read this properly ?

Comment: Can you post the data ,instead of picture?

Comment: No brother that got me an error

Comment: For getting 1: data['day'][1], for getting date in 1: data['day'][1].date

Comment: Its working on the snippet here ,may be try with parsing the data `console.log(JSON.parse(data).day['1'])`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the array form when the index is an interger, such as:

```js
let data = {
    "day": {
        "1": {
            "date" : "20200807"
        }
    }
}

console.log("data:", data);
console.log('data.day["1"]:', data.day["1"]);
console.log('data.day["1"].date:', data.day["1"].date);
```

Comment: When I log `console.log("data:", data);` I see data. But others suggestions I with got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the quotes like: `data.day[1]` instead of `data.day['1']`

```js
var data = 
    { 
        "status": 0,
        "location": "Casablanca [Doukkala-Abda;Morocco]",
        "day": {
            "1": {
                "date": "20200807",
                "name": "Friday",
                "month": ""
            },
            "2": {
                "date": "20200801",
                "name": "test",
                "month": ""
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(data.day[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is that you need to parse your API response with `JSON.parse()` first, like:

```js
let rawDataFromApi = '{"status":0,"location":"Casablanca [Doukkala-Abda;Morocco]","day":{"1":{"date":"20200807","name":"Friday","month":""}}}'

let data = JSON.parse(rawDataFromApi)

console.log(data['day']['1'])
```

Comment: I dont know why it does'nt work for me I tried all the possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
.  operator can be used to get the data.the data is a object so that [] will not be a good idea.
```

use `day.1.date` to get the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let data = {
    "day": {
        "1": {
            "date" : "202008071"
        }
    }
}
let data2 = {
    "day": {
        "2": {
            "date" : "202008072"
        }
    }
}
let data3 = {
    "day": {
        "third": {
            "date" : "202008073"
        }
    }
}
console.log(data.day["1"].date);
console.log(data2.day["2"].date);
console.log(data3.day["third"].date);
```

Comment: I got this error : `Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at C:\Users\..\app.js:43:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)`